# angular mat-checkbox dynamically with ngModel

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a class Offer which have one property "units" as array of objects.

```
export class Offer {
   public propertyA: string;
   public propertyB: string;
   public units: Unit[];
}

export class Unit {    
    public code: string,
    public name: string,
    public checked: boolean
}
```

I am using Angular2, these units must be checkboxes the user can select.
Also I am using angular material.

The html code looks like:

```
<div *ngFor="let unit of model.units; let i=index">
  <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="model.units[i].checked"
    id="units[{{i}}]" name="units[{{i}}]">
       {{ unit.name }}
  </mat-checkbox>                        
</div>
```

The units property is loaded using:

```
this.model.units.push(new Unit("code1","name1", false));
this.model.units.push(new Unit("code2","name2", false));
this.model.units.push(new Unit("code3","name3", false));
```

When I send the form the checked property does not contains the checked value.

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: Could you create a demo for this? I'm even wondering if this code works at all, since based on what I am seeing I would think that this code would actually throw errors.

Comment: Can you add your console errors if there's any?

Comment: Did you find a solution? If you find, please share it.

Answer (score 44):

Add `[checked]="unit.checked"` and remove `ngModel`, `id` and `name` from your `mat-checkbox`. This does one way binding when you load the page but to make the two way binding work you need to do something similar like this which i have done in my project:

Pass the `$event` on change and set the value in the component file manually:

Change your HTML to:

```
<div *ngFor="let unit of model.units">
  <mat-checkbox [checked]="unit.checked" 
  (change)="valueChange(model.units,unit,$event)">
       {{ unit.name }}
  </mat-checkbox>                        
</div>
```

Add this to Component file:

```
valueChange(model.units, unit, $event) {
        //set the two-way binding here for the specific unit with the event
        model.units[unit].checked = $event.checked;
    }
```

**EDIT/UPDATE**: Found a solution recently for two way binding without handling it explicitly

Make sure `model.units` have a property for `checked`. This is the easiest way to add it:

component.ts:

```
this.model.units.forEach(item => {
                       item.checked = false; //change as per your requirement
                    });
```

html:

```
 <div *ngFor="let unit of model.units;let i=index">
    <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="unit.checked" [checked]="unit.checked"                                                                                    
    name="{{i}}-name">  //make sure name is unique for every item                             
    </mat-checkbox>
</div>
```

If you want to control the enable/disable options as well try adding this:

component.ts:

```
this.model.units.forEach(item => {
                       item.checked = false;//change as per your requirement
                       item.disabled = true;//change as per your requirement
                        });
```

html:

```
<div *ngFor="let unit of model.units;leti=index">
        <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="unit.checked" [checked]="unit.checked"
         [disabled]="unit.disabled"                                                                                    
       name="{{i}}-name">//make sure name is unique for every item
        </mat-checkbox>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 11):

This work for me tested in Angular 7.

**Just to make sure that name is unique for each checkbox**

```
<mat-grid-list cols="4" rowHeight="100px">
                    <mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let item of aspNetRolesClaims" [colspan]="1" [rowspan]="1">
                        <span>{{item.claimValue}}</span>
                        <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="item.claimValue" name="{{item.claimType}}">{{item.claimType}}</mat-checkbox>
                    </mat-grid-tile>
                </mat-grid-list>
```

Answer (score 5):

> I tested in **Angular 7** and I couldn't find any error given your question and you can see a **working demo** in this [**StackBlitz example**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-answer-47384092?file=src/app/app.component.html), but here goes my answer.

**In order to work you gotta give an unique `name` to your ngModel binded input.**

Example taking your code:

```
<div *ngFor="let unit of model.units; let i=index">
  <mat-checkbox 
    [(ngModel)]="model.units[i].checked"
    id="units-{{i}}" 
    name="units-{{i}}" // using plain slug-case instead of array notation
  >
      {{ unit.name }}
  </mat-checkbox>                        
</div>
```

I prefer not to use the array notation in these cases (`units[{{i}}]`), because it means that all fields are joined in the same thing, but as your code seems to work this is just a preference and not the cause of the error.

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot use `[(ngModel)]` like when you are using a `FormGroup`, you can do the following. The code assumes that obj is the custom object and has a IsSeleted property.

```
<mat-checkbox [checked]="obj.IsSelected"                                      
 (change)="onSelectionChanged($event, obj)">{{obj.Name}}
</mat-checkbox>
```

And inside onSelectionChanged, update the obj.IsSelected manually

```
public onSelectionChanged(arg: MatCheckboxChange, obj:any) {
 obj.IsSelected = arg.checked;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One more possible way that might be simpler. This approach is working fine within a form group

```
<form [formGroup]='formGroup'>
    <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="obj.IsSelected" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone:> true}">
        {{obj.Name}}
    </mat-checkbox>
</form>
```