# dynamically insert mat-checkbox

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design

I want to dynamically insert a `<mat-checkbox>` element into a component.
and I inserted two `<mat-checkbox>` elements. one inserted statically (i.e into the template file directly).

and the other one inserted dynamically, and contains a `<mat-checkbox>` and another normal checkbox `<input type="checkbox" />`

the first one (the statically inserted one) rendered without any problem.

also the normal input inserted dynamically without any problem.

but the `<mat-checkbox>` that dynamically inserted didn't render as expected.

component.html:

```
<mat-checkbox> checkbox (static) </mat-checkbox>

<div [innerHTML] = "test2">
```

component.ts:

```
 this.test= ` 
     <mat-checkbox>mat-checkbox</mat-checkbox><br />
     <input type="checkbox" /> normal checkbox   
  `

  this.test2 = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.test);
```

I created a Reproduction on stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hsjevo

also I need to create checkboxes from categories, and append some extra spaces before each sub-category

i.e:

- category

  - sub category

    - sub of sub category
- category2

each category or sub-category is `<mat-checkbox value="$id"> $title`

Comment: That's not how you should us Angular to show dynamic content on your component. Use `*ngIf` / `*ngFor` for example to decide if something should be rendered depending on a component property.

Comment: Kindly take a look, this solved my issue Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47384092/angular-mat-checkbox-dynamically-with-ngmodel

Comment: I don't want to conditionally load a component. I want to dynamically add some html input to the existing component @ThomasSchneiter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

innerHTML property of div tag can only parse and render regular HTML elements like input, etc. To dynamically create Angular components like mat-checkbox, you need to inform Angular about those components. Let's see how this can be done below:

We need a placeholder in the AppComponent template where we can add the mat-checkbox component dynamically. We can use `<ng-template>` tag as a placeholder in this case.

**app.component.html**

```
<mat-checkbox>mat-checkbox (static)</mat-checkbox> <hr />


dynamic angular component:<br/>
<ng-template #placeholder></ng-template>
```

In AppComponent typescript file, we need to refer this placeholder and append the mat-checkbox component. Find the inline comments for explanation.

**app.component.ts**

```
import {
  Component,
  ComponentFactoryResolver,
  OnInit,
  Renderer2,
  ViewChild,
  ViewContainerRef
} from '@angular/core';
import {MatCheckbox} from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  // Get reference to the ng-template placeholder tag
  @ViewChild('placeholder', {read: ViewContainerRef, static: true}) placeholder: ViewContainerRef;

  constructor(
    private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    private renderer: Renderer2) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.createComponent();
  }

  createComponent() {
    // creating the mat-checkbox tag body content
    let content = this.renderer.createText(' mat-checkbox (dynamic)');
    // clear any previously appended element or component
    this.placeholder.clear();
    // resolve the MatCheckbox component and get the factory class to create the component dynamically
    let factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(MatCheckbox);
    // create the component and append to the placeholder in the template
    let ref = this.placeholder.createComponent(factory);
    // set the mat-checkbox body content
    (ref.location.nativeElement as HTMLElement).appendChild(content);
  }
}
```

In order for the above code to work, we need to inform Angular that we would be expecting to resolve the MatCheckbox component at runtime. Make the following changes in app.module.ts.

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatCheckboxModule, MatCheckbox } from '@angular/material';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';


@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, MatCheckboxModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent ],
  // Inform Angular about those components which will be created dynamically by including them in entryComponents field
  entryComponents: [ MatCheckbox ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Now you should be able to see the mat-checkbox created dynamically at runtime.
View the complete example here (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e7vhue)

For more information, refer this [article](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-dynamically-create-a-component-in-angular).

Hope this helped your query.

Comment: Ok, I want to fetch an array of inputs that will be converted into <mat-check>, each entry contains {title, id}.

indeed I want to form the checkboxes to append some extra spaces before every child category, So I think of fetching the inputs as string

Comment: @Sheldeeb Interesting. You can start appending multiple mat-checkbox component to the `ng-template` placeholder using the `createComponent` method of the `ViewContainerRef` reference. I have updated the app in the stackblitz for this usecase.

Comment: I just gave you vote +1 & accepted your answer @sharavan

Comment: How to add additional directives to he dynamically loaded components ex: `<mat checkbox [myDirective]="something">..</mat-checkbox>`

Comment: @Sheldeeb As far as I know, there is no way to add/remove directives programatically. Instead you can create a wrapper component (say, <custom-mat-checkbox>) and control the directive value through the wrapper component inputs. Have a look at the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60284184/how-to-dynamically-apply-a-tooltip-to-part-of-an-elements-dynamic-text-content/60287692#60287692) which does the same.