# Dynamically add a ngx-slick-carousel in Angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, data-binding

I'm using the [ngx-slick-carousel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-slick-carousel) module to create a carousel in my Angular 8 app. Everything works well when I call the directive from my html template,

e.g. `<ngx-slick-carousel class="carousel" #slickModal="slick-carousel" [config]="slideConfig">[...]</ngx-slick-carousel>`.

However now, I want to create a carousel dynamically and include it in an `[innerHtml]` which runs a pipe to override Angular sanitizer. Here is what my code looks like.

**foo.component.html:**

```
<div class="dynamic-content" [innerHtml]="dynamicHtml | safeHtml">
</div>
```

**foo.component.ts:**

```
// Imports
[...]

@Component({
    selector: 'app-foo',
    templateUrl: './foo.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./foo.component.scss'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class FooComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(
        [...]
    ) {
    }

    slideConfig = {
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        nextArrow: ('.next'),
        prevArrow: ('.prev'),
        infinite: false,
        swipeToSlide: true
    };

    public dynamicHtml = '';

    // This method is called at some point
    public createDynamicContent(condition) {
        if (condition) {
            this.dynamicHtml = `
            <ngx-slick-carousel class="carousel" #slickModal="slick-carousel" [config]="slideConfig">
                <div ngxSlickItem>
                    <!-- Some stuff inside the slide -->
                </div>
                <div ngxSlickItem>
                    <!-- Some stuff inside the slide -->
                </div>
                <div ngxSlickItem>
                    <!-- Some stuff inside the slide -->
                </div>
            </ngx-slick-carousel>`;
        } else {
            this.dynamicHtml = `<p><strong>Just some simple html</strong></p>`;
        }
    }
}
```

*Note: the `SlickCarouselModule` is imported in my `app.modules.ts` file, to allow myself to use it in all my components.*

From what I understand, the issue is that the carousel is initialized when the component is initialized, and at that point, my carousel does not exist yet. My question would be: **how do I dynamically create a ngx-slick-carousel**?

**Attempts so far**

After looking into the `node_modules` folder and trying to understand the code for the module, I tried to manually trigger the carousel initialization by adding the following code to my `foo.component.ts`:

```
import { SlickCarouselComponent } from 'ngx-slick-carousel';

[...]

@ViewChild(SlickCarouselComponent, {static: false})
public slickCarousel: SlickCarouselComponent = new SlickCarouselComponent();

[...]

// This method is called at some point
public createDynamicContent(condition) {
    if (condition) {
        this.dynamicHtml = [...];
        this.slickCarousel.initSlick();
    }
}
```

I obtained an error in my console: `this.slickCarousel.initSlick() is undefined`.

Comment: ngx-slick-carousel is not an regular HTML element where you can add it to innerHTML property of the div tag and expect the browser to parse and render it.

It is an Angular component and creating such components dynamically should be handled by Angular. Refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60264854/dynamically-insert-mat-checkbox/60267178#60267178) on how to create a Angular component dynamically.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment. Unfortunately `ngx-slick-carousel` is imported from my node modules so I don't have that much control on it, and when I try your solution from the linked post, I get an error saying `SlickCarouselModule cannot be used as an entry component`.

Comment: you should not add `SlickCarouselModule` in entryComponents array. You should add the `SlickCarouselComponent` because it is the component you are trying to add dynamically in runtime.