# How to dynamically apply a tooltip to part of an element's dynamic text content in Angular?

Tags: angular, tooltip, text-parsing, ngx-bootstrap

So I have this json file containing a dictionary.

`definitions.json`

```
{
  "word": "Some definition.",
  "an expression": "Some other definition."
}
```

And I have components throughout my app that may be similar to this.

`my.component.ts`

```
  @Component({
    selector: 'my',
    template: `
      <h1>{{ someTitleText }}</h1>
      <p>{{ someText }}</p>
    `

  })
  export class MyComponent {
    @Input() someTitleText: string;
    @Input() myText: string;
  }
```

I want to display a tooltip when the user will hover over a word that is present in the dictionary file and I need the tooltip to display the corresponding definition.

Making a parsing function to detect if and where a word or expression is present in a string is relatively trivial. Where I specifically need help is in figuring out the Angular way of adding the tooltip behavior to that specific word or expression inside the element once it has been detected.

ngx-bootstrap already has a [tooltip](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/tooltip#basic) and I would like to use that one rather than implement one from scratch.

What I need is the ability to somehow (structural directive, attribute directive, pipe, other???) selectively designate elements all over my app as having this behavior.

In other words, I need a reusable way to tell Angular "Hey, this element right here, I want you to check if it has some text content, and if some of that text is present in my dictionary, and if it is I want you to make it possible for the user to hover over that word or expression and for a tooltip to appear containing the appropriate definition for that word or expression."

Comment: `<h1 [title]="someTitleText"></h1>` ?

Comment: You're saying you don't know what element type the text will be in?

Comment: @hyperdrive Correct. In all likelyhood, the text will be inside a <p> or <h1-h6> element but I'd like a solution that would work with <div> <span> <whatev> if at all possible. If not, I can probably settle for a solution that will only work with <p> and <h1-h6>.

Comment: Not sure that i have fully understand, 
it depends on the link in your data,
You could use a map by 'word' on your definition.
Using it this way *ngIf="!!definitions[word]" on the div you apply the tooltip, at the same time you can find the definition with definitions[word]

Comment: @Koraxos I don't think this would quite work. my <p> element might contain the following string, passed in through an input prop: "If you think I'm sexy, and you like my body, come on baby let me know". My dictionary might contain the following entry:

```
{
  "sexy": "Quality possessed by the OP"
}
```

I need the word "sexy" to then be styled a bit differently (bold, or dotted underline, whatever) and open a tooltip on hover of that word only, not the rest of the <p>.

Answer (score 2):

It is easy to create an Angular component dynamically at run-time compared to an Angular directive. All you have to do is to create a wrapper Angular component (say, `TooltipComponent` that takes 2 inputs namely displayText and tooltipText) that applies the ngx-bootstrap tooltip directive to some HTML element of your choice. Then render this wrapper component dynamically for the word that is present in your dictionary.

I believe everything in the below code snippet is self-explanatory.

**app.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: "demo-tooltip-basic",
  template: `<p #para></p>`
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild("para", { static: false }) para: ElementRef<HTMLElement>;

  text = `I'm in love with the shape of you!`;
  dict = {
    love: "like something",
    shape: "blah!!!",
    something: "..."
  };

  ...

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.text.split(" ").forEach(word => {
      if (this.dict[word]) {
        let factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(TooltipComponent);
        let ref = factory.create(this.injector);
        ref.instance.text = `${word} `;
        ref.instance.tooltip = this.dict[word];
        ref.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
        this.renderer.appendChild(
          this.para.nativeElement,
          ref.location.nativeElement
        );
      } else {
        this.renderer.appendChild(
          this.para.nativeElement,
          this.renderer.createText(`${word} `)
        );
      }
    });
  }
}
```

To view the complete code of this app, use this stackblitz link (https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-tooltips).

I hope you can further improve this basic implementation to suit your needs. For more information on creating Angular components dynamically, view this [article](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-dynamically-create-a-component-in-angular).

**Note:** It is recommended to use `Renderer2` API provided by the Angular to safely create HTML elements at runtime.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The idea of a wrapping component is one of the first ideas that came to my mind. I might end up implementing it if I can't find another solution that is more reusable and semantically correct.

It feels weird to have to wrap text elements in another component element to apply changes to that text element. On the other hand, I guess it is akin to the decorator pattern in programming code. It's just seems like a weird way to do things in HTML templating.